# How to use "use" binding in SqlTransaction

Tags: f#

In MSSQL Server I have a database named `TestDB` that contains a single table with three column (Id, FirstName, LastName) named `TestTable`. To insert rows into `TestTable` I have declared a type

```
type Person = { Id:int; FirstName:string; LastName:string }
```

two methods 1) Parameters and 2) Transaction

```
let Parameters(person:Person) = 
    [|
        SqlParameter("@Id", person.Id)
        SqlParameter("@FirstName", person.FirstName)
        SqlParameter("@LastName", person.LastName)
    |]          

let Transaction(tsql, sqlcon, sqltran, sqlparam) =        
    let cmd = new SqlCommand(tsql, sqlcon, sqltran);
    for p in sqlparam do
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p) |> ignore
    cmd
```

in main method of my Console Application I have used the type and methods in this way

```
let population = [{Person.Id = 1; Person.FirstName = "Emon1"; Person.LastName = "Haque1"}
                  {Person.Id = 2; Person.FirstName = "Emon2"; Person.LastName = "Haque2"}]

let query = @"INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES(@Id, @FirstName, @LastName)"
let conStr = @"server=EMON; database=TestDB; user=TestUser; password=TestPass"      
use con = new SqlConnection(conStr)
con.Open()
let trans = con.BeginTransaction()

try
    population
    |> List.iter(fun x -> Transaction(query, con, trans, Parameters(x)).ExecuteNonQuery() |> ignore)
    |> trans.Commit
with
    | exn -> trans.Rollback()
```

I have used `use` once for `SqlConnection` in main method.

Should I use it for `SqlCommand` in `Transaction` function, `con.BeginTransaction()` and in case of calling Transaction as it returns `SqlCommand` in main method or `use con` will take care of all?

Comment: For higher level and type safe access to your DB you should consider using the [SqlClient](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/) or [SqlDataConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/tutorials/type-providers/accessing-a-sql-database) type providers. You can use `use` with objects that implement IDisposable but you will need to make sure  the object exists when you consume it (so apply `use` in the function scope you need the data).

Comment: @s952163 `SqlDataConnection` allows me to use LINQ extension methods, so it must be nice! In `fullContext` example for transaction they have written more than what I did here.  `fullContext.ExecuteCommand` expects an object array as parameter in which case I have to cast `Id, Firstname and LastName` as object right? Is there any issue of `boxing/unboxing` if I do so to make it an object array?

Comment: If you want to use LINQ extension methods you can reference and open some of the these namespaces: `System.Data.Linq`; `System.Linq`, `FSharp.Linq`. But [query expressions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/query-expressions) get the job done. I never use fullcontext btw, so need to check on how ExecuteCommand behaves (so you *might* be right), but using the type provider this way defeats the purpose. If you insist on using SQL I suggest then use SqlClient, or if you stick to the stock SQL type provider you can just update the columns in your dbSchema.

Comment: @s952163 `System.Linq` gives me all access to fluent syntax. `fullcontext` is same as `String.format` and can be used in this way `ExecuteCommand("INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES({0}, {1}, {2})", x.Id, x.FirstName, x.LastName)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're familiar with C#, then `use` works like `using` in C#. When the values go out of scope, `Dispose` is called. As a general rule, if you don't `use` values, then `Dispose` isn't called.

Some .NET APIs have options for disposing of contained disposable. As an example, `StreamReader` will automatically dispose of the `Stream` is contains, unless explicitly constructed with [a constructor overload where you can override that behaviour](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712952).

As far as I'm aware, though, there's no consistency in such APIs, so you can't rely on hierarchies of disposables to behave that way.

Specifically, I don't see any overloads of `BeginTransaction` that specify how the returned transaction relates to the connection that created it, and the documentation doesn't say, either. I'd `use` the `trans` value, instead of hoping that ill-defined behaviour in the BCL will do the right thing.

Comment: That's because usually an SqlTransaction object is created, which is indeed disposable, and can be `use`-d, and you'd pass both the connection and the command to the transaction object. Although this is more in reference to the OP.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Mark Seeman. `SqlCommand` is also disposable. Should I use `use cmd = Transaction(...)` in main method and `use cmd = new SqlCommand(...)` in Transaction function?

Comment: @MarkSeemann If I subscribe to its Disposed event, then the method is invoked only when I use `using`, So I think it is a must to have such deterministic disposal.

Comment: In F# if I do `cmd.Disposed.Add(fun x -> Console.WriteLine("Disposed"))` it gets called when I use `use`.